# Regex Match two specific characters and get first numbers followed by those Characters

Tags: python, regex, python-re

If user inputs **VX is 20 m/s VY is 40 m/s  VZ is 60 m/s**.

Expected results are the Axis VX and 20 from the input.

The code below also recognizes the other numbers 40 & 60 also.

```py
(VX)|(vx)|(Vx)|(vX)|[0-9]
```

Comment: Would you please try: [https://regex101.com/r/AJs0zc/1](https://regex101.com/r/AJs0zc/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(?P<axis>vx)\s+\w+\s+(?P<value>\d+)
```

Add `re.IGNORECASE`. See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/2d0gDG/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```
 - Named Capture Group axis (?P<axis>vx)
   - vx matches the characters vx literally (case insensitive)
 - \s+ matches any whitespace characters between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
 - \w+ matches any word characters between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
 - \s+ matches any whitespace characters between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
 - Named Capture Group value (?P<value>\d+)
   - \d+ matches a digits between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

**[Python code demo](https://tio.run/##JY7BCsIwEETv@Yq9NaFSRcWDaEWkiBcVhaLSS0ijDTRNSFKtXx@buoeBN7O7jP66SjUz74XUyjgwHDneOViDifIbCAvTCcixhfweYP4HyB@BFgNFSId1njAltag5NhHenFe0EzZ9d6SwcfGJew3mm9YtT4syJtEonBz2x9Ml222vGUGSOlb1n3RiOTWswqEIQeIJQ7JE0I82onF4MJKXUa0uBXOYEOT9Dw)**:

```py
import re
text = r'VX is 20 m/s VY is 40 m/s  VZ is 60 m/s'
p = re.compile(r'(?P<axis>vx)\s+\w+\s+(?P<value>\d+)', re.IGNORECASE)
match = p.search(text)
if match:
    print(match.groupdict())
```

**Results**: `{'axis': 'VX', 'value': '20'}`